# How to print all lines with a certain word in it in a text file

Tags: python

I need to write a program that takes a text file and asks the user for a word, then prints every line in which that word appears in.
Here's the code I have so far but it gives me an error:

```
text_file = open('gettysburg.txt', 'r').read()
key_word = input("What is the word?: ")

for line in text_file.readlines():
    if key_word in line:
       print(line)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _but it gives me an error_ -> Please! Always add the error message to your question

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
text_file = open('gettysburg.txt', 'r')   # you dont need .read here
key_word = input("What is the word?: ")

for line in text_file.readlines():
    if key_word in line:
       print(line)
```

`read` reads the entire content of file as a single string

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using `with` to open files (it's more recommended):

```
key_word = input("What is the word?: ")

with open('gettysburg.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    for line in text_file.readlines():
        if key_word in line:
            print(line)
```

Note it's python3.